# How to groupby and aggregate joining values as a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe structured like this:

```
df_have = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,3,4,4], 'desc':['yes','no','chair','bird','person','car']})
```

How can I get something like this:

```
df_want = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 'desc':['yes no','chair','bird','person car']})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby().apply`:

```
df_have.groupby('id', as_index=False)['desc'].apply(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
   id        desc
0   1      yes no
1   2       chair
2   3        bird
3   4  person car
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do `agg` with `groupby`

```
df = df_have.groupby('id',as_index=False)[['desc']].agg(' '.join)
   id        desc
0   1      yes no
1   2       chair
2   3        bird
3   4  person car
```